# Invoking method with custom delegate vs. action

Tags: .net, vb.net, invoke

I have seen Microsoft suggest using [a custom Delegate in the InvokeRequired pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But I can't figure out why one wouldn't just save the trouble of defining the delegate when doing something as simple as setting a control property. I'm referring to `Option 1` below which just uses the delegate `Action(Of String)` instead of a custom delegate.

```vb
' Option 1

Private Sub setLabelWorkingText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.lblWorking.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf setLabelWorkingText), [text])
    Else
        Me.lblWorking.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub

' Option 2

Private Delegate Sub setLabelWorkingTextDelegate(ByVal [text] As String)

Private Sub setLabelWorkingTextWithDel(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.lblWorking.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New setLabelWorkingTextDelegate(AddressOf setLabelWorkingTextWithDel), [text])
    Else
        Me.lblWorking.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

I understand one difference to be that arguments can't be passed ByRef using Action and Func, but a custom delegate can specify ByRef arguments. Are there any other differences between the two?

Comment: Sure.  Like many Winforms articles, and code, this was just written before these Action delegate types were added in .NET 3.5

Comment: @HansPassant heh good point. Unfortunately the MSDN article wasn't updated with newer releases of .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Action is essentially a custom delegate that's defined by way of a generic. I'm guessing the reason it's not specified in the pattern you linked to is that both the pattern and the Action delegate were developed/released at the same time, and the people developing the pattern and documentation may not have been familiar with the Action generic at the time of release. You'll notice that Action is used more often in examples and patterns for later releases of the Framework, as it gained acceptance.

Also, with regards to your comment on ByRef arguments to Action and Func, this is correct, but it's also trivial to implement a custom generic Action-like class that accepts parameters ByRef, as in:

```
Public Delegate Sub ActionByRef(Of T)(ByRef ref As T)

Sub Main()
    Dim sMyString As String = "Hello World"
    Dim actTrim As New ActionByRef(Of String)(AddressOf TrimFirst)
    actTrim.Invoke(sMyString)
    Console.WriteLine(sMyString) 'prints "ello World"
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub TrimFirst(ByRef s As String)
    s = s.Substring(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes but if one were to define all combinations of ByRef and ByVal for up to 16 arguments that's around 100, plus if they are overloads you won't be able to differentiate delegates of of the same number of arguments only by ref type.

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely simpler to write an `Action` compared to a `Delegate` if you can get away with it.

An `Action` just allows you to "pass a method as a parameter without explicitly declaring a custom delegate." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

When you pass a lambda function I think you're adding one more line to the call stack, but meh.